# Mocha test and subsequent calls to 'require' modules

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, browserify, typeahead.js

I have a project that uses Mocha test runner via the commandline (`mocha -- test/test-dir`) and Browserify. Currently the unit tests are very simple and we just require the source javascript (unbrowserified) to run the tests on. So far it has worked fine.

```
//test/test-dir/my-test.js

var foo = require('../../js/src/foo.js');
var assert = require('assert');

describe('foo.getBar', function() {
...
```

We recently wanted to add another dependency to `foo.js`, [typeahead.js](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js).

```
//js/src/foo.js

var jQuery = require("jquery");
var typeahead = require("typeahead.js");

...
```

Now our simple test fails with a `TypeError: _.mixin is not a function`. This `_.mixin` is [defined](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/dist/typeahead.bundle.js#L195) in typeahead.js but I'm suspecting that the nested require in `foo.js` is not being evaluated by Mocha?

Not too familiar with Mocha or Browserify, I thought that switching the test to use the browserified version of the `foo.js` would help as then the required modules would be built and available in `foo.min.js`, although I'm seeing the same error. I know that typeahead supports CommonJS packages so I'm not sure what is wrong with these tests? Any help would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I added [mochify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mochify) to handle what I believe to be some commonJS issues with Mocha. I'd love to know why this works but the tests pass now using `mochify -- test/test-dir/**/*.js` now. yay.